# How to update custom product feature value via PrestaShop WebService?

Tags: php, rest, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I need to set custom feature value when adding it by REST API.

Currently I've added features and included their ids in the xml, but it is still forcing me to set values options first, and than provide their id to the id_feature_value tag

```
<product_feature>
<id required="true"/>
<id_feature_value required="true"/>
</product_feature>
```

**How can I set custom value?**

If I take strategy to add temporary value, then read its id and update product I will be making unncessary load on server, I think there must be a way to add one time custom value, because it is possible to set one in the admin area.

Answer (score 0):

When you set a custom value for a feature in Prestashop Backoffice, that you are doing in reality is saving a value for this feature in database with it's own ID and the only difference is that the "custom" field in table "ps_feature_value" from BD is set to 1.
So to associate a feature value to a product is neccesary to save it before save the product via webservice.
If you go to `http://yourshop.com/api/product_feature_values?schema=synopsis` you can see the "custom" field.
The only difference between `custom = 1` or `custom = 0` it's the possibility to select it in the backoffice.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("template.xml");
$xml->addChild("product_feature_value");
$idfeature = $xml->product_feature_value->addChild("id_feature","idfeature:example=1");
$idfeature->addAttribute("href", PS_SHOP_PATH . "/api/product_features/2");

$value = $xml->product_feature_value->addChild("value");
$language = $value->addChild("language", "text");
$language->addAttribute("href", PS_SHOP_PATH . "/api/languages/1");
$language->addAttribute("id", 1);
$opt = array('resource' => 'product_feature_values');
$opt['postXml'] = $xml->asXML();
$xml2 = $webService->add($opt);
```